# Number of possible relations with following restrictions | Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am new to math. stack exchange, I am really not sure how I am supposed to ask this but I need a logical explanation and a way to logical way to approach questions like these. I tried doing it myself. Thank you.

The question is as follows:

$$\text{Let } A = \{a, b, c, d, f, g, h, k, u, x, z,y\}. \\$$

$(1)$ How many relations are there on $A$ that are reflexive, symmetric, and contain all the elements $(a,z), (u,u)$ and $(z,a)$?

(2) How many relations are there on $A$ that are antisymmetric and contain all the elements $(c,c), (x,a)$ and $(b,c)$, but do not contain the element $(c,b)$?

(3) ) ) How many relations are there on A that are reflexive, antisymmetric, and contain all the elements (x,a),(a,a),(b,d), and (a,z), but do not contain any of the elements (a,x),(a,b),(d,z),(z,d) or (c,d)?

My Solution

Let $A$ = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k,w,x,y,z}.

(1) . But I can use the formulas outlined for reflective and systematic. the formula is
$$2^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$$

since the last condition says, the relation should also include (a,z),(u,u), and (z, a). We will subtract 3 from the power of the whole expression as these elements are already contained.

(2) not sure about the other 2.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please avoid using pictures for the mathematical formulas in your posts: pictures make it harder for your readers and mean that your post won't show up in searches. Instead use [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is easy to learn and makes your mathematics look like it was professionally printed.

Comment: Yes.  Please edit this post rather than posting a dupe.  If your question is closed before you do so, edit it anyway and it will be considered for reopening (and likely reopened).

Comment: Yes.  I'd urge you, though, not to use the `text` delimiter because that's forcing people to scroll to read what you've wrote.  Just use normal text except for mathematical symbology.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you so much, I hope it is looking good now.

Comment: Your $A$ and $(A)$ are different. Is that intended?

Comment: They are the same @SassatelliGiulio. Thank you for noticing, I am still learning MathJax.

Comment: For the first one, requiring the reflexive property is a little misleading. It just means that $(a, a), (b, b), \ldots, (z, z)$ are all in the relation. You don't get to pick that. For the remaining, notice that symmetry demands that if you have $(M, N)$ in the relation, then you must have $(N, M)$ and vice-versa. So, you have 12 choose 2 possibilities minus the one given.

Comment: @TempusNomen,  I am not even sure If I did the questions the right way, apparent I did wrong ig. But I can use the formulas outlined for reflective and systematic.

the formula is $$2^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$$

since the last condition says, the relation should also include (a,z),(u,u), and (z, a).
We will subtract 3 from the power of the whole expression as these elements are already contained.

Comment: The title of a question should tell us something about the mathematics in the question, not something about the person posting the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What else do you need to solve this question sir?

Comment: I would suggest to change the tittle to "number of possible relations with following restrictions" or something along the lines

Comment: Understood, Changing it now. Thank you

Comment: "What else do you need to solve this question?" First, one doesn't solve a question. One may answer a question, or solve a problem, but one can't solve a question. Second, one needs some internal consistency in the question. You have a set $A$ that doesn't contain the element $r$, but in (2) you ask about $(r,a)$. You have two sets you call $A$, and they are different. If you can't be bothered to ask a coherent question, why should I put any effort into answering it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Hi Gerry I have fixed the problems. I am sorry made lots of mistakes while writing the question in MathJax. Yes, you are right, and I have fixed the issue now. I will try to read my questions thoroughly for the next time. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think it is better not representing the relation as $n^2$ directed pairs that either exist or not, but as a graph of $\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}$ general edges between 2 elements that can exist in 4 states - $a{\not-}b$, $a{\Rightarrow}b$, $a{\Leftarrow}b$, $a{\iff}b$ and $n$ self-edges that either are, $a{\iff}a$ or are not, $a{\not-}a$.

With $n$ being 12 makes it 66 normal and 12 self-edges

This way you can easily encompass requirements like reflexive or symmetric by simply excluding some of the states

- reflexive relation has simply all $n$ self-edges in the $a{\iff}a$ state
- symmetric relation can have the normal edges only in 2 states, $a{\not-}b$ or $a{\iff}b$
- antisymmetric relation can have the normal edges in 3 states, $a{\not-}b$, $a{\Rightarrow}b$, $a{\Leftarrow}b$

So

- in your $(1)$ it is reflexive and symmetric thus the normal edges can exist in 2 states only and the self-edges don't contribute, so you get ${\Large2}^{\left(\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2} - 1\right)}$ , subtracting the 1 known edge $a{\iff}z$
- in your $(2)$ you get ${\Large3}^{\left(\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2} - 2\right)} {\Large*} {\Large2}^{n-1}$ subtracting 2 normal edges and 1 self-edge with known states
- in your $(3)$ we get ${\Large3}^{\left(\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2} - 6\right)}{\Large*} {\Large2}^2$ as we know the exact states of $a{\Rightarrow}x$, $a{\Rightarrow}z$, $b{\Rightarrow}d$ and $d{\not-}z$ but for $ab$ there are still 2 possibilities left, $a{\not-}b$ or $a{\Leftarrow}b$ and the same goes for $cd$ ( we just subtract them from the 3-s and give them back as 2-s )

Comment: Why do you write such enormous numbers? :-)

Comment: normal numbers looked too small ... what size would be the best ? New around here. Not used to how the formulas end up looking.

Comment: test ${\large3}^{\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}}$ or ${\Large3}^{\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}}$ or ${\LARGE3}^{\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}}$

Comment: $3^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}$ is the norm here.

Comment: yea that was how I had it to begin with, no large size, but then the $3^{\left(\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2} - 7\right)}$ ended up looking too similar to ${\large3}{\left(\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2} - 7\right)}$

Comment: @MBobrik hi, thank you for the detailed answer. Yes you are right, I did make a typo while writing the question in MathJax. The actual question 3 is
) How many relations are there on A that are reflexive, antisymmetric, and contain all the elements (x,a),(a,a),(b,d), and (a,z), but do not contain any of the elements (a,x),(a,b),(d,z),(z,d) or (c,d)?

Comment: thus I edited my answer as well

Comment: @MBobrik Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.